# Какой dataSource нужно указывать для spring-quartz при работе с несколькими нодами?

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, quartz

Приложение на spring, развернутое на webshpere 8.5.5.13 с базой данных oracle 11g
Для запуска по расписанию использую spring-quartz

Веб-сервер представляет собой кластер с двумя нодами. Если создать просто trigger+job+scheduler - все ок, но джобы запускаются по расписанию сразу на всех нодах.

Поэтому выставил настройку

```
org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered = true
```

Но, что нужно указывать для параметра с датасорсом?

В spring-проекте датасорс подключен так(Определен в @Configuration классе Persistence.java):

```
@Bean
@Resource(type = DataSource.class, lookup = "jdbc/DATA", name = "jdbc/DATA")
public DataSource dataSource() {
    final JndiDataSourceLookup dsLookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
    dsLookup.setResourceRef(true);
    DataSource dataSource = dsLookup.getDataSource("java:comp/env/jdbc/DATA");
    return dataSource;
}
```

Так же есть файл c маппингом

> ibm-web-bnd.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-bnd
        xmlns="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee/ibm-web-bnd_1_0.xsd"
        version="1.0">

    <virtual-host name="default_host" />

    <resource-ref name="jdbc/DATA" binding-name="jdbc/DATA"/>
</web-bnd>
```

И на самой веб-сфере настроен DATA датасорс

я пробовал варианты указать для quartz в property-файле

```
org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource=java:comp/env/jdbc/DATA
org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource = jdbc/DATA
org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource = DATA
org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource = dataSource
```

но все они вызывают ошибку при работе приложения, что датасорс не найден.

Мне нужно создать отдельный датасорс для spring-quarz или что делаю не так?

Класс, для старта задач по расписанию:

package quartz;

```
@Configuration
@Import(PersistenceConfig.class)
@PropertySource(value = {"classpath:application.properties","classpath:quartz.properties"})
public class QuartzConfig {
    @Bean
    public JobDetail cronJob() {
        return JobBuilder.newJob(QuartzJob.class).withIdentity("helloJob").build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Trigger cronTrigger() {
        return TriggerBuilder
                .newTrigger()
                .withIdentity("helloTrigger")
                .withSchedule(SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule().repeatForever().withIntervalInSeconds(50))
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Scheduler cronScheduler(JobDetail cronJob, Trigger cronTrigger) throws SchedulerException {
        Scheduler scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.getDefaultScheduler();
        scheduler.scheduleJob(cronJob, cronTrigger);
        scheduler.start();
        return scheduler;
    }
}
```

Сама задача

```
public class QuartzJob implements Job{
    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass());

    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext jobExecutionContext) throws JobExecutionException {
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "========HELLO========%n");
    }
}
```

---

c ошибкой в датасорсе разобрался по [этой](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46327762/quartz-there-is-no-datasource-named-myds) ссылке.
Но, при срабатывании триггера, quartz пытается записать свое состояние в бд, но не находит в таблицу. 
Ищу как должна выглядеть эта таблица чтобы он мог в нее писать и как называться.

> org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.LockException: Failure obtaining db row
>   lock: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist  [See nested exception:
>   java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not
>   exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скрипты для построения БД различных версий лежат [здесь](https://github.com/quartz-scheduler/quartz/tree/master/quartz-core/src/main/resources/org/quartz/impl/jdbcjobstore). Не забудь сменить branch на ту версию, которую ты используешь.